# Cannot access newly created 'View' page in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter framework. In that I created a new Controller called 'blog.php' inside application/controllers. This 'blog.php' has the following code:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class blog extends CI_Controller {

  public function view($page = 'blog_view')
    {
      $this->load->view('blog_view');
    }
}
```

And in application/views I created 'blog_view.php' and this file has the following code:

```
<h1>BLOG VIEW</h1>
```

Now I have two issues:

1. How can I access this blog_view page in url? My project name is 'ci'. When I access 'localhost/ci' I'm able to view the 'welcome' page.
2. What should I do to add another page's link, like 'about' page in blog page itself? For example in static sites we add anchor tag with about.html in href.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try renaming view to index()

Comment: Yes. This fixed the issue. Thanks a lot. Now I added a link for blog view page in home page and when I click it, it is correctly redirecting to the blog view page with this url 'http://localhost/ci/index.php/blog'. Is there any way to have a clean url, so that when I click that link, it must redirect to this same page with clean url, like 'http://localhost/ci/blog'. What should I do in 'routes.php'?

Comment: That is ask so many times just search on google on how to remove index.php from url even on youtube some videos on it.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont use .htaccess try this 
http://localhost/ci/index.php/blog

To remove index.php create .htaccess file in your ci folder and put this code inside it

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

http://localhost/ci/blog

to add more page add more controller for example to create about page

create new controller with name about

```
 <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class about extends CI_Controller {

  public function view($page = 'blog_view')
    {
      $this->load->view('about_view');
    }
}
```

and the view

```
<h1>About VIEW</h1>
```